How to retreive Checkbox selections from a flow and copy into email
I have a flow with a checkbox group that has 3 choices.  The flow works fine and the user can select multiple choices in the checkbox.  Question is: how can I retrieve these choice selections and put them into an email?
In my email, I have tried using  {!Degree_Checkbox} but it's blank.  I'm not sure how to do this.
Checkbox API name is Degree_Checkbox
Choices are Degree_AA, Degree_BS, Degree_MA

Hi, for clarity, where are you constructing the Email body that you are attempting to send? Is this a Text Template in the Flow being passed as the body, or is this an Email Template you have created and are then referencing?

the email body is being constructed from within the Flow.  Both the checkbox and the email are within the flow

It would be useful to see the configuration of the Flow if possible. I've just tried in a demo org, and using a text template the selected values are displayed as expected.

@CallumMacErlich   When I debug the flow, I can see which choices were selected, but do not know how to format the text template to show those choices.

Ah that is the issue. You can't reference the choices, you need to reference the actual input. That was what you had included in your question, have you changed that since you asked?

I must have changed it as I was doing a lot of trial and error...so I would want to use the {!Degree_Checkbox} resource?

Yep, that will output the selected values

So this is strange...I use this resource {!Degree_Checkbox} in a Text Template, and when I display this text template on a Screen as Display Text, all the values show up as they should.   When I use the exact same text template as an email body, these values are blank.  They are the only ones that are blank..all others are fine.

Could you add a screenshot of the configuration? Of both the text template and the calling of the send email action?
